# Lower bound on distance to optimality for smooth and convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am reading this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.00313.pdf which is about the Polyak step size.

It states that in the proof of Lemma 2 (Second point) we use equation 2:

> For smooth functions, equation (2) implies:
> $$d^2_{t+1}-d_t^2 \leq - \frac{\gamma h_t}{2\beta}$$

where $d_t = ||x_t-x^*||_2^2$ and $h_t = f(x_t)-f(x^*)$

When I look at equation 2, then I can follow the argument, assuming that $\frac{1}{2\beta} ||\nabla f(x_t)||^2 \leq h_t$ where $\beta$ is the smoothness parameter. This was proven by Lemma 4 in the "Elementary properties of convex analysis" appendix. However, I do not follow the proof for case 3 in for this Lemma. It starts with an assumption: $h_t \geq \frac{1}{\beta}||\nabla f(x_t)||^2$ which I do not understand.

Why are we able to say that for any smooth convex function, this holds: $h_t \geq \frac{1}{\beta}||\nabla f(x_t)||^2$ ? I assume that this is a fairly important statement, but can't find any reference in Boyds convex optimization.

Comment: That's a typo. They are restating what they are trying to prove (it can't be an assumption, since it's not used anywhere in the proof) and it seems that they have omitted the $2$ in the denominator by mistake.

Comment: Isn't this required for the last step? If you plug in the polyak step size for eta, and then use the lower bound of h_t you get the last inequality?

Comment: Sorry, it seems you are right. However I think you can show the desired inequality (the one that Lemma 4 is proving) without this assumption. In fact you can show that $f(y) - f^* \geq \frac{1}{2 \beta} \| \nabla f(y) \|^2$ for any vector $y$ when your function is $\beta$-smooth. Have a look at [Lieven Vanderberghe's UCLA Lecture notes](https://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf).